# java query save it in a list<String> persistence jpql

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I have to implement this metod

```
public List<String> getAuthorArticlesPercentageForCategory (String categoryText) {
    /* in this query i count the articles in a spesific category*/
    Query q=em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(ar) FROM Article ar WHERE ar.categoryId.categoryText=:categoryText")
    .setParameter("categoryText", categoryText);
    Long n=(Long)q.getSingleResult();   
    /* in this query i found the authors and count the articles which they wrote in the spesific category */  
    Query  w=em.createQuery( "SELECT ar.authorId.firstName,count(ar) FROM Article ar WHERE ar.categoryId.categoryText=:categoryText GROUP BY ar.authorId"); 
    w.setParameter("categoryText", categoryText); 
    List list1=w.getResultList();  
    /*stop here i cant go on*/
    return list;
```

This list has to return a `List<String>` with this format:

name: (ar.authorId.firstName) , category(categoryname), percentage (this must be count(ar) from 2query/n)

Comment: so whats the point in getting the "n"?

Comment: n is from first query. this is the count(articles) from a spesific category. I want to find the percentage of articles published by each author

Answer (score 0):

You use an entitymanager object.So returning a list ,use q.getresultlist().
Then iterate for(String str:list1) etc.